# Old JPG files only work with VB6 leadtools

Tags: image-processing, vb6, leadtools-sdk

I have images that I wanna show it on the web. The extension of the image is .JPG. If you open the file in notepad it starts with LTRI. But that page is not working on browser (even not working on Photos/Paint app of windows 10). It only works on VB6 LeadTools. How can I convert this image? File metadata is below,

[image]

Comment: This is not JPEG but proprietary LeadTools format

Comment: To be exact (taken from [here](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/CMP)): it is the LEAD CMP 1-bit file header that _begins with ascii "LTRI"_

Comment: There seems to be a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Formats.Raster.Common/) You could start from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [LeadTools libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Formats.Raster.Common/). You'll need to register to their site.

I haven't seen anyone else supporting that format, that is proprietary (as written by @Selvin).

Then the code should be easy:

```
using (RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs())
{
    var image = codecs.Load("yourimage.ext");
    // 0 should means "whatever bit format is appropriate"
    codecs.Save(image, "out.jpg", Leadtools.RasterImageFormat.Jpeg, 0);
}
```

Comment: Remember that you are reencoding the image. If you save it to jpg you'll lose a little quality. Probably there is an option somewhere to control the quality of the saved jpg. Make some tests if it is better to convert to jpg or png

Answer (score 2):

The answer posted by xanatos is correct. This appears to be a 1-bit LEAD CMP image file.

We would like to add the following details:

1. If the images are indeed 1-bit CMP, they would be pure black-and-white, and they would be lossless (unlike color CMP and common JPEG, which are usually lossy formats).
2. Naming the file aa.JPG is incorrect, since the recommended extension for LEAD images is “.CMP”. However, when using our SDK, the correct format is detected regardless of the file name or its extension.
3. Converting 1-bit images to JPEG is not recommended, since JPEG files are more suited for full-color images. It’s better to save them as PNG, TIFF or other lossless formats. (The LEADTOOLS SDK supports many such formats).
   Using lossless compression shouldn’t produce large files since 1-bit images contain a lot less data than full-color images.
4. When using the free evaluation of our SDK, technical support is free through chat and email, so feel free to contact us with any questions you have.